# How to change Java Compilance Level to Java 1.7 from Java 1.6 for all plugins created in Java 1.6

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I have set of plugins which were created in Java 1.6 before, now I want to change the java compliance level to Java 1.7 as I want to migrate to Java 7. Is there any way that I can change this for all plugins at once. Currently I am seeing that I need to change it for all the plugins one by one.

Regards,

Anand

Comment: How many plugins do you actually have that are affected?  Are you making a mountain out of a molehill here?

Comment: We have more than 500 plugins to change. We just migrated to Java 7 but the plugins are still pointing to old Java 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first question would be, do you *really* need to make all the projects use Java 7 compliance right away? A more reasonable approach might be to migrate then as-needed. If you're not going to put Java-7-specific code in every project, I don't see why they'd *all* need to change compliance level.

If for some reason you really want to do that, there's no UI to do it. What you can do is set up one of the projects first, which will create or modify a file in that project's `.settings` folder; then you can then copy that file to the other projects. You might have to **Refresh** the other projects or use **Project > Clean** to get Eclipse to pick up the change.

What (I think) you're really looking for is discussed (but never implemented) in [this very old feature request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=194414). It's disappointing that nobody ever stepped up to implement that, because it would be very powerful; but, as consumers of open source software, we're all to blame when a desired feature isn't implemented.